# How do I open a url in a new tab in a firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm creating a firefox plugin that opens a website in a new tab when the toolbar button is clicked. 
When I click the toolbar button I don't get a response. Is there anything I'm missing in my code?

Part 1:

```
var app = function () {
 var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
  return {
    init : function () {
      gBrowser.addEventListener("load", function () {
        var toRun = prefManager.getBoolPref("extensions.app.autorun");
        if (autoRun) {
          app.run();
        }
      }, false);
    },

    run : function () {
      var head = content.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
      style = content.document.getElementById("app-style"),
      allLinks = content.document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
      foundLinks = 0;

      if (!style) {
        style = content.document.createElement("link");
        style.id = "app-style";
        style.type = "text/css";
        style.rel = "stylesheet";
        style.href = "chrome://app/skin/skin.css";
        head.appendChild(style);
      } 
    },

    click : function () {
      gBrowser.addEventListener("click", function () {
        gBrowser.addTab("https://www.google.com");
      }, false);
    },
  }
};
```

part 2:

```
function installButton(toolbarId, id, afterId) {
  if (!document.getElementById(id)) 
    var toolbar = document.getElementById(toolbarId);
  // If no afterId is given, then append the item to the toolbar
  var before = null;
  if (afterId) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(afterId);
    if (elem && elem.parentNode == toolbar)
      before = elem.nextElementSibling;
  }

  toolbar.insertItem(id, before);
  toolbar.setAttribute("currentset", toolbar.currentSet);
  document.persist(toolbar.id, "currentset");

  if (toolbarId == "addon-bar")
     toolbar.collapsed = false;
   }
};

Application.getExtensions(function (extensions) {
  var extension = extensions.get("app@app.com");
  installButton("nav-bar", "app-toolbar-button");
});

window.addEventListener("load", app.init, false);
window.addEventListener("click", app.click, false);
```

Comment: Did you check if the gBrowser object is initialized when making the call? Do you see any error messages in the console?

Comment: I do get an error message:
error: ReferenceError: extvar is not defined. source file: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul. line 1. 
line 1 of that file says <?xml version="1.0"?>.

Comment: That error means there is a syntax error in your JavaScript. Please post the entire contents of your JS file.

Comment: The entire js file is now in the question. I updated it a bit. The new error I'm seeing is Error: ReferenceError: app is not defined Source File: chrome://browser/content/browser.xul.I'm still being directed to browser.xul line 1 in the error console.

Comment: FYI this does not seem to be related to the Add-on SDK.

Comment: Why are you attaching another click event listener in `app.click`?

Comment: Why didn't you use normal chrome.manifest + overlay.xul? It is faster and doesn't rely on third-party JS code...

Comment: What do you mean, another click event listener?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use normal way (these are excerpts from my regular addon):

1) chrome.manifest file

```
# ... here is packages definitions ... 

# Overlays for Mozilla Firefox
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://xpcomviewer/content/overlay-firefox.xul
# This is needed for toolbar
style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://xpcomviewer/skin/overlays.css

# ...
```

2) content/overlay.xul

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://xpcomviewer/skin/overlays.css" type="text/css"?>

<!DOCTYPE overlay [
    <!ENTITY % brandDTD SYSTEM "../locale/en-US/brand.dtd">
    %brandDTD;
    <!ENTITY % overlayDTD SYSTEM "../locale/en-US/overlays.dtd">
    %overlayDTD;
]>

<overlay id="eXpcomViewerBrowserOverlay"
         xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <script type="application/javascript" 
            src="chrome://xpcomviewer/content/overlays.js"></script>

    <!-- Toolbar palette overlay -->
    <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
        <toolbarbutton id="xpcomviewer-toolbarbutton" 
                       class="toolbarbutton-1" 
                       oncommand="xpcomviewer.overlay.open();" 
                       label="&xpcomviewerCmd.label;"
                       accesskey="&xpcomviewerCmd.key;" 
                       tooltiptext="&xpcomviewerCmd.tip;"/>
    </toolbarpalette>

</overlay>
```

3) content/overlay.js

```
/* Copyright (c) 2007-2012 ondrejd.info
   See the file LICENSE.txt for licensing information. */

/*
#include "global.js"
*/

// Namespace
if(typeof(xpcomviewer) == "undefined") var xpcomviewer = {};
if(typeof(xpcomviewer.overlay) == "undefined") xpcomviewer.overlay = {};
// Implementation of xpcomviewer.overlay
(function() {

    /** @type String */
    const kFIREFOX_ID = "{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}";
    /** @type String */
    const kSEAMONKEY_ID = "{92650c4d-4b8e-4d2a-b7eb-24ecf4f6b63a}";
    /** @type String */
    const kTHUNDERBIRD_ID = "{3550f703-e582-4d05-9a08-453d09bdfdc6}";

    /** @type String */
    const kWIN_URI = "chrome://xpcomviewer/content/xpcomviewer.xul";

    /** @type Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch */
    const kPREF_SRV = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].
            getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService).
            getBranch("extensions.xpcomviewer.");

  /**
   * Opens XPCOMViewer.
   * 
   * @returns {void}
   */
  this.open = function() 
  {
    let useTab = kPREF_SRV.getBoolPref("useTab");

    if(useTab === true) {
      this.openInTab();
    } else {
      this.openInWindow();
    }
  }; // end open()

  /**
   * Opens XPCOMViewer in a standalone window.
   * 
   * @returns {void}
   */
  this.openInWindow = function()
  {
    let win = window.open(
        kWIN_URI,
        "xpcomviewer", 
        "chrome,extrachrome,menubar,toolbar,resizable,all"
        );

        win.focus();
  }; // end openInWindow()

  /**
   * Opens XPCOMViewer in a new tab if is running on Firefox, SeaMonkey or 
   * Thunderbird. Otherwise opens in a new window.
   * 
   * @returns {void}
   */
  this.openInTab = function()
  { 
        let appInfo = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xre/app-info;1"].
                getService(Components.interfaces.nsIXULAppInfo);  

        if(appInfo.ID == kFIREFOX_ID || appInfo.ID == kSEAMONKEY_ID) {  
            xpcomviewer.global.openUrlInInternalBrowser(kWIN_URI);
        } else if(appInfo.ID == kTHUNDERBIRD_ID) {  
            xpcomviewer.global.openUrlInContentTab(kWIN_URI);
        } else {  
            this.openInWindow();
        }
  }; // end openInTab()

}).apply(xpcomviewer.overlay);
```

4) skin/overlay.css

```
@import url("chrome://global/skin/");
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

/* Copyright (c) 2005-2012 Ondrej Donek.
 * See the file LICENSE.txt for licensing information. */

.icon16 {
    list-style-image: url("chrome://xpcomviewer/skin/icons16.png");
    -moz-image-region: rect(16px 16px 32px 0px);
}

#xpcomviewer-toolbarbutton {
    list-style-image: url("chrome://xpcomviewer/skin/icon22.png");
}
toolbar[iconsize="small"] #xpcomviewer-toolbarbutton {
    list-style-image: url("chrome://xpcomviewer/skin/icons16.png");
    -moz-image-region: rect(16px 16px 32px 0px);
}
#mini-xpcomviewer {
    list-style-image: url("chrome://xpcomviewer/skin/icons16.png");
    -moz-image-region: rect(16px 16px 32px 0px);
}
```

Comment: I know that this is not exactly answer on your question - but I think that you'll have no troubles you have now with this approach.